# debug-on-error vs. debug-on-signal (in json.el in particular)

Tags: debugging, emacs, elisp

My expectation would be for `debug-on-error` to trap most anomalous events and show me what went wrong.  <del>However, this is not the case with [`json.el`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/json.el) which uses `signal` instead of `error`.</del>

The [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Error-Debugging.html) cautions against using `debug-on-signal` and my brief experimentation with it pretty much confirms this -- there are signals all over the place, so I would have to trap on just the `json-`* signals to get anything useful out of this.  But I can't get even that to work.

I was about to submit a bug report for `json.el` but I feel that I may be missing something.  Is there a good, established reason why `json.el` prefers `signal` over `error`?

Steps to repro:

```
(require 'json)
(setq debug-on-error t
      debug-on-signal t)  ; "json" ; '("json") ;; Still nothing
(json-read-from-string "")
```

Somewhat more realistically, you would have an actual, real-life problem when you pass the output from something to `json-read` (or one of its convenience wrappers `json-read-from-string`, `json-read-file`, `json-read-object`, etc)  and it doesn't contain what you expect.

The result, even with `debug-on-signal` set to `t`, is the following text in the `*Messages*` buffer, and not much else:

with no indication as to the source of the error, or anything.  (In real code with a similar problem, I was seeing `if: End of file during parsing` .)

Comment: I originally linked to old documentation at http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/elisp-manual-21/elisp_225.html which has even stronger language: "**Warning:** This variable is strong medicine!"

Comment: See also now http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=19768

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the default value of `debug-ignore-errors` includes `end-of-file` so you have to remove that to be able to debug this particular problem.

```
(delete 'end-of-file debug-ignored-errors)
```

or perhaps more realistically

```
(let (debug-ignored-errors)
   (json-something))
```

to temporarily override the value of `debug-ignored-errors` for the duration of the `json-something` call.

... and then you don't need `debug-on-signal` at all.

So my speculation that the use of `signal` instead of `error` causes the problematic behavior turned out to be false.

Comment: I'd still appreciate an answer which clarifies when one should use `signal` instead of `error`.

Comment: `error` and `user-error` are just convenience wrappers to `signal`, each with a particular error symbol set.  Just like exception handling in other languages, it can be useful to give specific names to particular conditions, so that you can `condition-case` those conditions explicitly.

Comment: I see that a community bump to this question led to me replying to a 5 year old comment :)  That was probably entirely redundant!

Comment: `C-h i g (elisp)Error Symbols` has most of the details.  If testing, note that `define-error` should be used to declare any such symbols, as `condition-case` ignores a handler condition symbol if it's lacking an `error-conditions` property.